# How can I access my models in django admin?

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I am working on an AlumniTracker in django and till now I have created forms for user sign up and some additional information.
Even after saving the additional information form I am not able to access it in django-admin.

I am adding my models, views and forms file here.

views.py

```
def student_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentDetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            student_form = form.save(commit=False)
            student_form.user = request.user
            student_form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('homepage'))
    else:
        form = StudentDetailForm()

    return render(request, 'authentication/student_profile.html', {'form':form})


def alumni_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AlumniDetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            alumni_form = form.save(commit=False)
            alumni_form.user = request.user
            alumni_form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('homepage'))
    else:
        form = AlumniDetailForm()

    return render(request, 'authentication/student_profile.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class StudentDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentDetail
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'contact_no', 'birth_date', 'course', 'session_start', 'session_end']


class AlumniDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AlumniDetail
        exclude = ['user']
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=PROFILE_CHOICES, default='student')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class StudentDetail(models.Model):
    first_name    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name     = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact_no    = models.IntegerField()
    birth_date    = models.DateField()
    course        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    session_start = models.IntegerField()
    session_end   = models.IntegerField()
    user          = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class AlumniDetail(models.Model):
    first_name    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name     = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact_no    = models.IntegerField()
    birth_date    = models.DateField()
    course        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    session_start = models.IntegerField()
    session_end   = models.IntegerField()
    company       = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

open and edit admin.py
and register your models by adding code below admin import

```
from .models import CustomUser,StudentDetail,AlumniDetail

admin.site.register(CustomUser)
admin.site.register(StudentDetail)
admin.site.register(AlumniDetail)
```

Comment: I have already done that.. the models are being shown in the admin page, but the content of the form is not there

Comment: does your form completion redirect to homepage ? if not the form might not be valid , and ill like to see your template.